# numpy rollaxis - how exactly does it work?

Tags: python, numpy

So I was experimenting with numpy and I ran across a strange (?) behavior in the rollaxis method.

```
In [81]: a = np.ones((4, 3, 2))

In [82]: a.shape
Out[82]: (4, 3, 2)

In [83]: x = np.rollaxis(a, 2)

In [84]: x.shape
Out[84]: (2, 4, 3)

In [85]: np.rollaxis(x, -2).shape
Out[85]: (4, 2, 3)
```

Shouldn't the -2 reverse the rollaxis? What I'm trying to do is apply a matrix that can only be applied when the 2 coordinate is first. But then I want to put my array back into its original form. The only things which I have found to work are applying `np.rollaxis(x, 2)` twice, or applying `np.rollaxis(x, 0, start=3)`. I just found these by guessing and I have no idea why they work. They also seem to be obscuring what I'm really trying to do. Could somebody please explain the way that I should 'reverse' a roll, or what I'm doing wrong?

(Is there a pythonic way to do this?)

Comment: It may be insightful to understand how `np.rollaxis` works, but let me tell you - better just forget it and learn `np.moveaxis` (a better version of this) immediately. For example: `np.moveaxis(a, 0, 3)` moves first dimension to fourth. This is the equivalent of `np.rollaxis(a, 0, 4)`. The reverse operations are - correspondingly: `np.moveaxis(a, 3, 0)` and `np.rollaxis(a, 3)`. `np.moveaxis` can change many dimensions at a time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The method `rollaxis`

```
def rollaxis(a, axis, start=0):
```

reallocates the chosen `axis` at the `start` "position"

Following your example:

```
a = np.ones((4, 3, 2))
x = np.rollaxis(a, 2)
# x.shape = (2, 4, 3)
```

Concerning shapes: `rollaxis` will bring the number `2`, which is in your last `axis=2`, to the the first position, since `start=0`.

By using

```
x2 = np.rollaxis(x, -2)
# x2.shape = (4,2,3)
```

`rollaxis` will bring the number 4, which is the second last axis, `axis=-2`, and reallocate at the first position, since `start=0`. That explains your result `(4,2,3)`, instead of `(4,3,2)`.

Following the same logic, this explains why applying `rollaxis(a,2)` twice brings the array shape back to the initial one. `np.rollaxis(x, 0, start=3)` also works because the first axis goes to the last one, in other words the number 2 in (2,4,3) goes to the last position resulting (4,3,2).

Comment: So just to recap: to invert the effect of `rollaxis(x,n)`, use `rollaxis(x,0,n+1)`.

Comment: The inverse uses n+1 and not n because "The axis is rolled until it lies *before* this position." (quote: docs).

Answer (score 8):

`np.rollaxis(tensor,axis,start)` moves the axis specified by the axis parameter to the position before the axis that is located at start with no exceptions.

Say the axes are `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` if axis points to the 3, and start points to the 5, then after the roll, the 3 will be just before the 5. Since the 3 in my example is at position 2 of the dimensions tuple, `axis=2`. Also, since the 5 is at position 4, `start=4`.

Like this:

```
>>> a.shape

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

>>> np.rollaxis(a, 2, 4).shape

(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6)
```

As you can see, the 3 is now right before the 5.
NOTE: The 3 does not move to position 4, but rather to the position before the value originally at position 4 (which in this case turns out to be position 3).

Negative numbers specify positions just like they do for lists. In other words, `axis=-1` specifies the last position. In my example above there is a 6 in the -1 position and a 5 in the -2 position. Both axis and start may be negative.

You can do the same thing I did above with negative numbers like this:

```
>>> a.shape

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

>>> np.rollaxis(a, -4, -2).shape

(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6)
```

If start is not specified, it defaults to 0 which is the first position. That means that if start is not specified, the specified axis will always be moved to the beginning, which is before the 1 which was originally at position 0.

If this is confusing there is another explanation that might make more sense here:
[Reason why numpy rollaxis is so confusing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891583/reason-why-numpy-rollaxis-is-so-confusing)

Comment: How would you bring the specified axis to the last position? `np.rollaxis(a,1,len(a.shape))` would do the trick, but it looks like a hack.

Comment: `axis` needs to be in range `[-len(a.shape), len(a.shape)-1]` (inclusive), and `start` `[-len(a.shape), len(a.shape)]` (inclusive), so there's no hack here.

Comment: *** This will move the second axis to the end ***
>>> import numpy as np;
>>> a = np.ones((1,2,3,4,5));
>>> a.shape;
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 1, 5).shape;
(1, 3, 4, 5, 2)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that it **moves around the axis of the nd-array**.
It takes the axis mentioned by `axis` parameter and puts it in the *position* mentioned by the `start` parameter; while this happens, the remaining axes in the following positions till the end will move towards right. If you ignore the `start` parameter, it moves the mentioned axis to the first position (i.e. it will be moved as 0th axis)

Let's understand it with an example:

```
In [21]: arr = np.ones((3,4,5,6))

In [22]: arr.shape
Out[22]: (3, 4, 5, 6)
# here 0th axis is 3, 1st axis is 4, 2nd axis is 5, 3rd axis is 6

# moving `3`rd axis as `1`st axis
In [27]: np.rollaxis(arr, 3, 1).shape

# see how `6` which was the third axis has been moved to location `1`
Out[27]: (3, 6, 4, 5)
```

While moving the axis (or *rolling* as NumPy calls it), the already existing axis in that position makes room for the incoming axis and that and the following axes move as a block towards right side.

If you ignore the `start` parameter, the axis in the `axis` parameter will be moved to the front (i.e. to the 0th position).

```
In [29]: a.shape
Out[29]: (3, 4, 5, 6)

# ignoring the `start` moves the axis to the very front position.
In [30]: np.rollaxis(arr, 3).shape
Out[30]: (6, 3, 4, 5)
```

---

Comparison with **`np.moveaxis`**

```
In [38]: arr.shape
Out[38]: (3, 4, 5, 6)

In [39]: np.rollaxis(arr, 0, -1).shape
Out[39]: (4, 5, 3, 6)

In [40]: np.moveaxis(arr, 0, -1).shape
Out[40]: (4, 5, 6, 3)
```

Observe in the above example how `np.moveaxis` does circular shift while `np.rollaxis` just *extends* only towards right side.

---

PS: Also, note that this *rollaxis* operation **returns a view** of the input array starting from *NumPy 1.10.0*

Answer (score 0):

It will have the same result when axis==start and axis == start-1

```
>>>a=np.ones([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> np.rollaxis(a, axis=2, start=2).shape
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> np.rollaxis(a, axis=2, start=3).shape
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```