# Wrapped (circular) 2D interpolation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have angular data on a domain that is wrapped at `pi` radians (i.e. 0 = `pi`). The data are `2D`, where one dimension represents the angle. I need to interpolate this data onto another grid in a wrapped way.

In one dimension, the `np.interp` function takes a period `kwarg` (for `NumPy` 1.10 and later): 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

This is exactly what I need, but I need it in two dimensions. I'm currently just stepping through columns in my array and using `np.interp`, but this is of course slow.

Anything out there that could achieve this same outcome but faster?

Comment: Have you looked into [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`?](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d)

Comment: Yes, and there's no analogous implementation of a period. Do you have a specific workaround in mind?

Comment: Interpolate the data.  Create a function that maps the values of φ and r to your dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An explanation of how `np.interp` works

Use the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1570-L1692), Luke!

The [numpy doc for `np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) makes the source particularly easy to find, since it has the link right there, along with the documentation. Let's go through this, line by line.

First, recall the parameters:

```
"""
x : array_like
    The x-coordinates of the interpolated values.
xp : 1-D sequence of floats
    The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing if argument
    `period` is not specified. Otherwise, `xp` is internally sorted after
    normalizing the periodic boundaries with ``xp = xp % period``.
fp : 1-D sequence of floats
    The y-coordinates of the data points, same length as `xp`.
period : None or float, optional
    A period for the x-coordinates. This parameter allows the proper
    interpolation of angular x-coordinates. Parameters `left` and `right`
    are ignored if `period` is specified.
"""
```

Let's take a simple example of a triangular wave while going through this:

```
xp = np.array([-np.pi/2, -np.pi/4, 0, np.pi/4])
fp = np.array([0, -1, 0, 1])
x = np.array([-np.pi/8, -5*np.pi/8])  # Peskiest points possible }:)
period = np.pi
```

Now, I start off with the `period != None` branch in the source code, after all the type-checking happens:

```
# normalizing periodic boundaries
x = x % period
xp = xp % period
```

This just ensures that all values of `x` and `xp` supplied are between `0` and `period`. So, since the period is `pi`, but we specified `x` and `xp` to be between `-pi/2` and `pi/2`, this will adjust for that by adding `pi` to all values in the range `[-pi/2, 0)`, so that they effectively appear after `pi/2`. So our `xp` now reads `[pi/2, 3*pi/4, 0, pi/4]`.

```
asort_xp = np.argsort(xp)
xp = xp[asort_xp]
fp = fp[asort_xp]
```

This is just ordering `xp` in increasing order. This is especially required after performing that modulo operation in the previous step. So, now `xp` is `[0, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4]`. `fp` has also been shuffled accordingly, `[0, 1, 0, -1]`.

```
xp = np.concatenate((xp[-1:]-period, xp, xp[0:1]+period))
fp = np.concatenate((fp[-1:], fp, fp[0:1]))
return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)   # Paraphrasing a little
```

`np.interp` does linear interpolation. When trying to interpolate between two points `a` and `b` present in `xp`, it only uses the values of `f(a)` and `f(b)` (i.e., the values of `fp` at the corresponding indices). So what `np.interp` is doing in this last step is to take the point `xp[-1]` and put it in front of the array, and take the point `xp[0]` and put it after the array, but after subtracting and adding one period respectively. So you now have a new `xp` that looks like `[-pi/4, 0, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi]`. Likewise, `fp[0]` and `fp[-1]` have been concatenated around, so `fp` is now `[-1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0]`.

Note that after the modulo operations, `x` had been brought into the `[0, pi]` range too, so `x` is now `[7*pi/8, 3*pi/8]`. Which lets you easily see that you'll get back `[-0.5, 0.5]`.

---

### Now, coming to your 2D case:

Say you have a grid and some values. Let's just take all values to be between `[0, pi]` off the bat so we don't need to worry about modulos and shufflings.

```
xp = np.array([0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4])
yp = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
period = np.pi

# Put x on the 1st dim and y on the 2nd dim; f is linear in y
fp = np.array([0, 1, 0, -1])[:, np.newaxis] + yp[np.newaxis, :] 
# >>> fp
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [-1,  0,  1,  2]])
```

We now know that all you need to do is to add `xp[[-1]]` in front of the array and `xp[[0]]` at the end, adjusting for the period. Note how I've indexed using the singleton lists `[-1]` and `[0]`. This is a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183182/525169) to ensure that [dimensions are preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3551242/525169).

```
xp = np.concatenate((xp[[-1]]-period, xp, xp[[0]]+period))
fp = np.concatenate((fp[[-1], :], fp, fp[[0], :]))
```

Finally, you are free to use [`scipy.interpolate.interpn`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interpn) to achieve your result. Let's get the value at `x = pi/8` for all `y`:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
interp_points = np.hstack(( (np.pi/8 * np.ones(4))[:, np.newaxis], yp[:, np.newaxis] ))
result = interpn((xp, yp), fp, interp_points)
# >>> result
# array([ 0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5])
```

`interp_points` has to be specified as an Nx2 matrix of points, where the first dimension is for each point you want interpolation at the second dimension gives the x- and y-coordinate of that point. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357219/525169) for a detailed explanation.

If you want to get the value outside of the range `[0, period]`, you'll need to modulo it yourself:

```
x = 21 * np.pi / 8
x_equiv = x % period   # Now within [0, period]
interp_points = np.hstack(( (x_equiv * np.ones(4))[:, np.newaxis], yp[:, np.newaxis] ))
result = interpn((xp, yp), fp, interp_points)
# >>> result
# array([-0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5])
```

Again, if you want to generate `interp_points` for a bunch of x- and y- values, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39357219/525169).

Comment: PS: There's likely a few typos in the code. I'll check and correct them shortly.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good point about concatenating the wrapped values onto the data, and I can probably figure it out from there. But for the good of future interpolators, would you consider cleaning this up so that it contains working code, tests a relevant example (interpolating onto values outside [0, pi)), etc?