# Using scipy interpn with meshgrid on an n-dimensional array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, interpolation, n-dimensional

I am trying to translate a Matlab "interpn" interpolation of a large, 4D array, but formulations diverge significantly between Matlab and Python. There's a good question/answer from several years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332053/using-scipy-interpolate-interpn-to-interpolate-a-n-dimensional-array/39357219#39357219) that I've been trying to work with. I think I am almost there, but apparently still don't have my grid interpolator properly formulated.

I modeled my code example after the example given in the linked answer above as closely as I could, while using the dimensions I am actually working in. The only change is that I switched rollaxis for moveaxis, as the former is deprecated.

Essentially, given the 4D array skyrad0 (which is dependent on the four elements defined in the first code block) together with two constants and two 1D arrays defined in the third block, I want the interpolated 2D result.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
import numpy as np

# Define the data space in the 4D skyrad0 array
solzen = np.arange(0,70,10)     # 7
aod = np.arange(0,0.25,0.05)    # 5
index = np.arange(1,92477,1)    # 92476
wave = np.arange(350,1050,5)    # 140

# Simulated skyrad for the values above
skyrad0 = np.random.rand(
    solzen.size,aod.size,index.size,wave.size) # 7, 5, 92476, 140

# Data space for desired output values of skyrad 
# with interpolation between input data space
solzen0 = 30                    # 1
aod0 = 0.1                      # 1
index0 = index                  # 92476
wave0 = np.arange(350,1050,10)  # 70

# Matlab
# result = squeeze(interpn(solzen, aod, index, wave,
#                   skyrad0,
#                   solzen0, aod0, index0, wave0))

# Scipy
points = (solzen, aod, index, wave)             # 7, 5, 92476, 140
interp_mesh = np.array(
    np.meshgrid(solzen0, aod0, index0, wave0))  # 4, 1, 1, 92476, 70
interp_points = np.moveaxis(interp_mesh, 0, -1) # 1, 1, 92476, 70, 4
interp_points = interp_points.reshape(
    (interp_mesh.size // interp_mesh.shape[3], 
    interp_mesh.shape[3]))                      # 280, 92476

result = interpn(points, skyrad0, interp_points)
```

I am expecting a 4D array "result" that I can numpy.squeeze into the 2D answer I need, but the interpn yields the error:

```
ValueError: The requested sample points xi have dimension 92476, but this RegularGridInterpolator has dimension 4
```

Where I am foggiest on this example is the structure of the meshgrid of query points, and the moving of the first dimension to the end and reshaping it. There is more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286537/numpy-efficient-way-to-generate-combinations-from-given-ranges/27286794#27286794), but it's still not clear to me how to apply that to this problem.

A bonus would be if anyone can identify clear inefficiencies in my formulation. I'll need to run this type of interpolation thousands of times on a number of different structures -- even extending to 6D -- so efficiency is important.

**Update** The answer below solved the problem very elegantly. However, as the calculations and arrays become more complicated, another problem creeps in, namely what appears to be a problem with elements in the array that do not increase monotonically. Here is the problem reframed in 6D:

```
# Data space in the 6D rad_boa array
azimuth = np.arange(0, 185, 5) # 37
senzen = np.arange(0, 185, 5) # 37
wave = np.arange(350,1050,5)    # 140
# wave = np.array([350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 410, 440, 470, 510, 550, 610, 670, 750, 865, 1040, 1240, 1640, 2250]) # 18
solzen = np.arange(0,65,5)     # 13
aod = np.arange(0,0.55,0.05)    # 11
wind = np.arange(0, 20, 5)      # 4

# Simulated rad_boa
rad_boa = np.random.rand(
    azimuth.size,senzen.size,wave.size,solzen.size,aod.size,wind.size,) # 37, 37, 140/18, 13, 11, 4

azimuth0 = 135              # 1
senzen0 = 140               # 1
wave0 = np.arange(350,1010,10) # 66
solzen0 = 30                # 1
aod0 = 0.1                  # 1
wind0 = 10                  # 1

da = xr.DataArray(name='Radiance_BOA',
                data=rad_boa,
                dims=['azimuth','senzen','wave','solzen','aod','wind'],
                coords=[azimuth,senzen,wave,solzen,aod,wind])

rad_inc_scaXR = da.loc[azimuth0,senzen0,wave0,solzen0,aod0,wind0].squeeze()
```

As it stands, it runs, but if you change the definition of wave to the commented line, it throws the error:

```
KeyError: "not all values found in index 'wave'"
```

Finally, in response to a comment below (and to help boost efficiency), I am including the structure of the HDF5 file (created in Matlab) from which this "rad_boa" 6D array is actually built (this example above only uses a simulated random array). The actual database is read into Xarray as follows:

```
sdb = xr.open_dataset(db_path, group='sdb')
```

And the resulting Xarray looks something like this:
[image: Xarray VSC guide]

Answer (score 2):

**Why a ValueError?**

First of all, `scipy.interpolate.interpn` requires that `interp_points.shape[-1]` is the same as the number of dimensions in your problem. That's why you're getting a `ValueError` from your code snippet -- your `interp_points` has 92476 as `n_dims`, which clashes with the actual number of dims (4).

**Quick fix**

You can fix this code snippet by simply changing the order of your operations. You are trying to squeeze too early -- if you squeeze *after* the interp:

```
points = (solzen, aod, index, wave)                 # 7, 5, 92476, 140
mg = np.meshgrid(solzen0, aod0, index0, wave0)      # 4, 1, 1, 92476, 70
interp_points = np.moveaxis(mg, 0, -1)              # 1, 1, 92476, 70, 4
result_presqueeze = interpn(points, 
                            skyrad0, interp_points) # 1, 1, 92476, 70
result = np.squeeze(result_presqueeze,
                    axis=(0,1))                     # 92476, 70
```

I've replaced `interp_mesh` with `mg` here, and removed the `np.array` (it's not required, as `np.meshgrid` returns an `ndarray` object).

**Comments on performance**

I think your code snippet is fine, however you may wish to use `xarray` if you're handling labelled data, as it is:

- a bit more readable than unlabeled `numpy` arrays
- can also handle some of the background work using [dask](https://dask.org/) (useful if you are examining large amounts of data in 6D)

*Update*: Oops! This should have been `.interp`, not `.loc`. The code snippet below worked because the data points were in fact original data points. As a warning to others:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpn
import numpy as np
from xarray import DataArray

# Define the data space in the 4D skyrad0 array
solzen = np.arange(0,70,10)     # 7
aod = np.arange(0,0.25,0.05)    # 5
index = np.arange(1,92477,1)    # 92476
wave = np.arange(350,1050,5)    # 140

# Simulated skyrad for the values above
skyrad0 = np.random.rand(
    solzen.size,aod.size,index.size,wave.size) # 7, 5, 92476, 140

# Data space for desired output values of skyrad 
# with interpolation between input data space
solzen0 = 30                    # 1
aod0 = 0.1                      # 1
index0 = index                  # 92476
wave0 = np.arange(350,1050,10)  # 70

def slow():
    points = (solzen, aod, index, wave)                 # 7, 5, 92476, 140
    mg = np.meshgrid(solzen0, aod0, index0, wave0)      # 4, 1, 1, 92476, 70
    interp_points = np.moveaxis(mg, 0, -1)              # 1, 1, 92476, 70, 4
    result_presqueeze = interpn(points, 
                                skyrad0, interp_points) # 1, 1, 92476, 70
    result = np.squeeze(result_presqueeze,
                        axis=(0,1))                     # 92476, 70
    return result

# This function uses .loc instead of .interp!
"""
def fast():
    da = DataArray(name='skyrad0',
                   data=skyrad0,
                   dims=['solzen','aod','index','wave'],
                   coords=[solzen, aod, index, wave])

    result = da.loc[solzen0, aod0, index0, wave0].squeeze()

    return result
"""
```

By making a couple of modifications to the updated code snippet given by the OP:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

azimuth = np.arange(0, 185, 5) # 37
senzen = np.arange(0, 185, 5) # 37
#wave = np.arange(350,1050,5)    # 140
wave = np.asarray([350, 360, 370, 380, 390, 410, 440, 470, 510,
                   550, 610, 670, 750, 865, 1040, 1240, 1640, 2250]) # 18
solzen = np.arange(0,65,5)     # 13
aod = np.arange(0,0.55,0.05)    # 11
wind = np.arange(0, 20, 5)      # 4

coords = [azimuth, senzen, wave, solzen, aod, wind]

azimuth0 = 135              # 1
senzen0 = 140               # 1
wave0 = np.arange(350,1010,10) # 66
solzen0 = 30                # 1
aod0 = 0.1                  # 1
wind0 = 10                  # 1

interp_coords = [azimuth0, senzen0, wave0, solzen0, aod0, wind0]

# Simulated rad_boa
rad_boa = np.random.rand(
    *map(lambda x: x.size, coords)) # 37, 37, 140/18, 13, 11, 4

def slow():
    mg = np.meshgrid(*interp_coords)
    interp_points = np.moveaxis(mg, 0, -1)
    result_presqueeze = interpn(coords, 
                                rad_boa, interp_points)
    result = np.squeeze(result_presqueeze)
    return result

def fast():
    da = xr.DataArray(name='Radiance_BOA',
                    data=rad_boa,
                    dims=['azimuth','senzen','wave','solzen','aod','wind'],
                    coords=coords)

    interp_dict = dict(zip(da.dims, interp_coords))

    rad_inc_scaXR = da.interp(**interp_dict).squeeze()
    return rad_inc_scaXR
```

This is pretty speedy:

```
>>> %timeit slow()
2.09 ms ± 85.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit fast()
343 ms ± 6.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> np.array_equal(slow(),fast())
True
```

You can find more about `xarray` interpolation [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html). Dataset instances have very similar syntax.

It's also possible to change the interpolation method as desired (perhaps, one may wish to supply the keyword argument `method='nearest'` to `.interp` for a discrete interpolation problem).

**More advanced stuff**

If you are looking to implement something more advanced, I would recommend perhaps using one of the implementations of the MARS (Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines). It falls somewhere between standard regression and interpolation, and works for multidimensional cases. In Python 3, your best bet is [`pyearth`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth).

Comment: Perfect; even better as the true skyrad is actually and xarray already (read in from and HDF5 per skyrad0 = xr.open_dataset(db_path)['skyrad0']), although I'm currently unable to reference it directly with loc (working on it), and have to build da from its elements as the example to get it to work.

Comment: Glad to help. If you get stuck, feel free to edit your original post to include the string representation of your Dataset imported via `xarray.open_dataset` for everyone to have a look at. Depending on the form of your HDF5 file, sometimes it can be easier to import it as a DataArray (`xarray.open_dataarray`) and then construct your Dataset manually.

Comment: I have edited my question to add another issue regarding monotonically increasing values, as well as the code used to pull in the actual database from the HDF5 file into Xarray and a screenshot of the database structure that results.

Comment: I've updated my response. Note that it previously used `.loc` erroneously, instead of `.interp` -- nothing to do with linearly spaced points, just simply that all of the points were actually in your original set of coordinates.