# How to efficiently interpolate a 3D array on a finer, uniformed-spacing grid?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a 3D array and want to interpolate it into a finer resolution grid. The 3D array is defined on a regular grid with even spacing. The interpolation is also on a regular grid with even spacing. The step size is `2^(-n), n=0,1,2,3 ...`. Interpolation should be either linear or higher order Bspline. For example, a 3D array `a` has sizes of (3,3,5) and the step size of the interpolation grid is `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`(n=1). Then the interpolation grid is defined as

```
x=np.linspace(0,2,num=5) # 3/0.5-1 = 5
y=np.linspace(0,2,num=5) # 3/0.5-1 = 5
z=np.linspace(0,4,num=9) # 5/0.5-1 = 9
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, sparse=True)
```

Then the output array should have sizes of (5,5,9). Which interpolation function in scipy or numpy can do the job in a most efficient way?

Comment: have you looked at the [many interpolation options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) from scipy?

Comment: Yes, but I could not find regular even grids to regular even grid for 3D array. I have seen there are RegularGridInterpolator and map_coordinates, but they are designed to solve more general problems.

Comment: [scipy.interpolate.interpn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html#scipy.interpolate.interpn) interpolates on regular grids of arbitrary dimension

Comment: @David I have looked the interpn function, but could not find a good example about it. Could you give an example of how to use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332053/using-scipy-interpolate-interpn-to-interpolate-a-n-dimensional-array/39357219

Answer (score 1):

I have found zoom is the most efficient function to do it. Check it out: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html