# How to generate staircase number sequence using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to generate a list of number sequences using python, like below.

```
[0,0,0,0] [0,0,0,1] [0,0,0,2] [0,0,1,1] [0,0,1,2] [0,0,2,2] [0,1,1,1]
[0,1,1,2] [0,1,2,2] [0,2,2,2] [1,1,1,1] [1,1,1,2] ... [2,2,2,2]
```

Right now, I can do this using pure python with a recursive call, but it takes a lot of time for a single run (a few hours). I wonder if it's possible to do this with numpy and save a huge amount of time, and if yes, how?

Comment: Take time to read this post on how to compose a good SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Hint: Include code you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement). From the docs:

> `combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2)
>   AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD`

Hence:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(it.combinations_with_replacement((0, 1, 2), 4))
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 2, 2),
 (0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2, 2),
 (0, 2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 2)]
```

The best part of this method is that since it returns a generator, you can iterate over it without storing it. This is a huge plus, since it'll save you a *lot* of memory.

#### Other implementations and timing

Here are some more implementations, including a numpy implementation. `combinations_with_replacement` (the `try2` function) appears to be the fastest:

```
import itertools as it
import timeit

import numpy as np

def try1(n, m):
    return [t for t in it.product(range(n), repeat=m) if all(a <= b for a, b in zip(t[:-1], t[1:]))]

def try2(n, m):
    return list(it.combinations_with_replacement(range(n), m))

def try3(n, m):
    a = np.mgrid[(slice(0, n),) * m] # All points in a 3D grid within the given ranges
    a = np.rollaxis(a, 0, m + 1)     # Make the 0th axis into the last axis
    a = a.reshape((-1, m))           # Now you can safely reshape while preserving order
    return a[np.all(a[:, :-1] <= a[:, 1:], axis=1)]

>>> %timeit b = try1(3, 4)
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.1 µs per loop
>>> %timeit b = try2(3, 4)
The slowest run took 8.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 µs per loop
>>> %timeit b = try3(3, 4)
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.8 µs per loop
```

This is true even for bigger numbers:

```
>>> %timeit b = try1(3, 6)
1000 loops, best of 3: 654 µs per loop
>>> %timeit b = try2(3, 6)
The slowest run took 7.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.33 µs per loop
>>> %timeit b = try3(3, 6)
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
```

**Notes:**

- I was using python3
- I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755410/525169) for the implementation of `try1`.
- I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286794/525169) for the implementation of `try3`.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean this (or how is the sequence you mean defined)?

```
from itertools import product

for item in product((0, 1, 2), repeat=4):
    print(item)
```

this prints:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 2)
...
(2, 2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

not sure if that is what you are looking for, but [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is included in python.

this should be fast and memory-efficient. the lists are created on demand.

...on second thought: this is probably what you mean, right?

```
for a, b, c, d in product((0, 1, 2), repeat=4):
    if not a <= b <= c <= d:
        continue
    print(a,b,c,d)
```

with output:

```
0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 1, 0 0 0 2, 0 0 1 1, 0 0 1 2, 0 0 2 2, 0 1 1 1, 
0 1 1 2, 0 1 2 2, 0 2 2 2, 1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 2, 1 1 2 2, 1 2 2 2, 
2 2 2 2,
```

and now i see how you would want that more efficient...

looks like [Praveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41422171/4954037) provides just that.