# How to improve this List Comprehensions?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I wonder I can improve my python code to be written shorter.
I only use standard library and numpy library. 
Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
x=1
y=2
np.array([(a,b,c) for a in [x,y] for b in [x,y] for c in [x,y]])
```

As you can see, this program produces all three combinations of elements.
There is a similar part in this program like `for a in [x, y]` and can it be written shorter?

[Edited]

I want to use only standard library and numpy library.

The inputs should be any values like x=3, y=8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: efficient way to generate combinations from given ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286537/numpy-efficient-way-to-generate-combinations-from-given-ranges)

Comment: [Numpy: efficient way to generate combinations from given ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286537/numpy-efficient-way-to-generate-combinations-from-given-ranges) is similar in generating a combination of all values. But their input values are continuous number. I want to use any values as input. (I forgot to write this condition in my question, sorry.)

Comment: Based on a similar question [Junkrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11135962/junkrat) suggested, I come up with the idea. I wrote the code as one of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

# ...
np.array(list(product((x, y), repeat=3)))
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure this would improve performance by much since you still do  a `list(product(...))` i.e a loop comprehension.

Comment: Performance was never the issue. Even if `numpy.array` accepted any iterable, it would have to iterate it to create the array.

Comment: But I'm sorry that I was supposed to use only standard library and numpy library, but I could not specify it.

Comment: I mistakenly think that itertools is not in the standard python library, but it is. So, using itertools may be the simplest way now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a similar question [Junkrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11135962/junkrat) suggested, I come up with the idea. (But it is not simple.)

```
import numpy as np
x=1
y=2
a = np.array(np.meshgrid([x, y], [x, y], [x, y]))   
a = np.rollaxis(a, 0, 4)         
a = a.reshape((2*2*2, 3))
```