# Reason why numpy rollaxis is so confusing?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The behavior of the numpy rollaxis function confuses me.
The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) says:

> Roll the specified axis backwards, until it lies in a given position.

And for the `start` parameter:

> The axis is rolled until it lies before this position.

To me, this is already somehow inconsistent.

Ok, straight forward example (from the documentation):

```
>>> a = np.ones((3,4,5,6))
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 1, 4).shape
(3, 5, 6, 4)
```

The axis at index 1 (4) is rolled backward till it lies before index 4.

Now, when the `start` index is smaller than the `axis` index, we have this behavior:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 3, 1).shape
(3, 6, 4, 5)
```

Instead of shifting the axis at index 3 before index 1, it ends up at 1.

Why is that? Why isn't the axis always rolled to the given `start` index?

Comment: I concur, the documentation  (and the observed behavior ) do not match. Also the documentation does not mention that one can use negative indices (as with python list indexing) to count backwards. There appears to be at least one issue on GitHub concerning this topic.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22583792/1461210

Comment: Are the corresponding `transpose` inputs any easier to understand?  `np.transpose(a,[0,2,3,1]).shape` and `np.transpose(a,[0,3,1,2]).shape`

Comment: In the 2nd case, `a.shape[3]` ends up before `a.shape[1]`, `6` before `4`.  In the 1st case, there isn't a `a.shape[4]`, so the insert is at the end.

Comment: I don't understand what the term rolling an axis means? Does it mean rotating the index array when it says rolling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much of the confusion results from our human intuition - how we think about moving an axis.  We could specify a number of roll steps (back or forth 2 steps), or a location in the final shape tuple, or location relative to the original shape.

I think the key to understanding `rollaxis` is to focus on the slots in the original shape.  The most general statement that I can come up with is:

Roll `a.shape[axis]` to the position before `a.shape[start]`

`before` in this context means the same as in list `insert()`.  So it is possible to insert before the end.

The basic action of `rollaxis` is:

```
axes = list(range(0, n))
axes.remove(axis)
axes.insert(start, axis)
return a.transpose(axes)
```

If `axis<start`, then `start-=1` to account for the `remove` action.

Negative values get `+=n`, so `rollaxis(a,-2,-3)` is the same as `np.rollaxis(a,2,1)`.  e.g. `a.shape[-3]==a.shape[1]`.  List `insert` also allows a negative insert position, but `rollaxis` doesn't make use of that feature.

So the keys are understanding that `remove/insert` pair of actions, and understanding `transpose(x)`.

I suspect `rollaxis` is intended to be a more intuitive version of `transpose`.  Whether it achieves that or not is another question.

---

You suggest either omitting the `start-=1` or applying across the board

Omitting it doesn't change your 2 examples.  It only affects the `rollaxis(a,1,4)` case, and `axes.insert(4,1)` is the same as `axes.insert(3,1)` when `axes` is `[0,2,3]`.  The `1` is still placed at the end.  Changing that test a bit:

```
np.rollaxis(a,1,3).shape
# (3, 5, 4, 6)   # a.shape[1](4) placed before a.shape[3](6)
```

without the `-=1`

```
# transpose axes == [0, 2, 3, 1]
# (3, 5, 6, 4)  # the 4 is placed at the end, after 6
```

If instead `-=1` applies always

```
np.rollaxis(a,3,1).shape
#  (3, 6, 4, 5)
```

becomes

```
(6, 3, 4, 5)
```

now the `6` is before the `3`, which was the original `a.shape[0]`.  After the roll `3` is the the `a.shape[1]`.  But that's a different `roll` specification.

It comes down to how `start` is defined.  Is a postion in the original order, or a position in the returned order?

---

If you prefer to think of `start` as an index position in the final shape, wouldn't it be simpler to drop the `before` part and just say 'move `axis` to `dest` slot'?

```
myroll(a, axis=3, dest=0) => (np.transpose(a,[3,0,1,2])
myroll(a, axis=1, dest=3) => (np.transpose(a,[0,2,3,1])
```

Simply dropping the `-=1` test might do the trick (omiting the handling of negative numbers and boundaries)

```
def myroll(a,axis,dest):
    x=list(range(a.ndim))
    x.remove(axis)
    x.insert(dest,axis)
    return a.transpose(x)
```

Comment: Good explanation, however I think the flaw in this implementation is distinguishing the `axis < start` case from the `axis >= start` case. If this was omitted (or `start -= 1` for both case), the behavior would be consistent.

Comment: Actually I see `start` as an index in the list of axes. Since the number of axes doesn't change, it doesn't matter if `start` refers to the original or the resulting axis order. Basically calling `np.rollaxis(a, 3, 1)` says "I want the axis at index 3 to be moved to index 0 (before 1)",  just like in the `np.rollaxis(a, 1, 3)` example where the axis at index 1 is moved to index 2 (before 3).

Comment: I added an alternative roll that uses a `dest` index instead of a 'before start'.

Comment: For also handling negative indexes just do `axis %= a.ndim` and `dest %= a.ndim`.

Comment: Honestly it seems to me that the `-=` "correction" is a mistake that stuck once the devs got used to it. I can think of no reason why these two should give the same behavior: `np.rollaxis(a, 1, 1)` and `np.rollaxis(a, 1, 2)`. And there is no elegant way to get any axis to be the last axis (which honestly is the use I am mainly desiring). I should get it from `np.rollaxis(a, axis, -1)` but I have to check `ndim` to do it: `np.rollaxis(a, axis, a.ndim)` which seems silly since `rollaxis` checks `ndim` internally already.

Answer (score 16):

NumPy v1.11 and newer includes a new function, [`moveaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html), that I recommend using instead of `rollaxis` (disclaimer: I wrote it!). The source axis always ends up at the destination, without any funny off-by-one issues depending on whether `start` is greater or less than `end`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
for i in range(5):
    print(np.moveaxis(x, 3, i).shape)
```

Results in:

```
(4, 1, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 4, 2, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.arange(1*2*3*4*5).reshape(1,2,3,4,5)

np.rollaxis(a,axis,start)
```

'axis' is the index of the axis to be moved starting from 0. In my example the axis at position 0 is 1.

'start' is the index (again starting at 0) of the axis that we would like to move our selected axis before.

So, if start=2, the axis at position 2 is 3, therefor the selected axis will be before the 3.

Examples:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(a,0,2).shape # the 1 will be before the 3.

(2, 1, 3, 4, 5)

>>> np.rollaxis(a,0,3).shape # the 1 will be before the 4.

(2, 3, 1, 4, 5)

>>> np.rollaxis(a,1,2).shape # the 2 will be before the 3.

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

>>> np.rollaxis(a,1,3).shape # the 2 will be before the 4.

(1, 3, 2, 4, 5)
```

So, after the roll the number at axis before the roll will be placed just before the number at start before the roll.

If you think of rollaxis like this it is very simple and makes perfect sense, though it's strange that they chose to design it this way.

So, what happens when axis and start are the same? Well, you obviously can't put a number before itself, so the number doesn't move and the instruction becomes a no-op.

Examples:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(a,1,1).shape # the 2 can't be moved to before the 2.

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

>>> np.rollaxis(a,2, 2).shape # the 3 can't be moved to before the 3.

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

How about moving the axis to the end? Well, there's no number after the end, but you can specify start as after the end.

Example:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(a,1,5).shape # the 2 will be moved to the end.

(1, 3, 4, 5, 2)

>>> np.rollaxis(a,2,5).shape # the 3 will be moved to the end.

(1, 2, 4, 5, 3)


>>> np.rollaxis(a,4,5).shape # the 5 is already at the end.

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```