# How to determine a numpy-array reshape strategy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a python project I often find myself reshaping and re-arranging n-dimensional numpy arrays. However, I have a hard time to determine how to approach the problem, visualize the outcome of the results of the reshaping methods and knowing my solution is efficient.

At the moment when confronted with such a problem my strategy is to start ipython, load some sample data and go trial and error until I find a combination of transpose()s, reshape()s and swapaxes()s. which gets the desired result. It gets the job done, but without a real understanding of what is going on and often produces code which is hard to maintain.

So, my question is about finding a strategy. How do you approach such a problem? How do you visualize an ndarray in your head when you have to shape it in the desired format? How do you come to the right actions?

To make answering a bit more concrete, an example to play with:

Assume you want to reshape the following 3d-array

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

to a 2d-array where the first columns from the 3rd dimension are placed first, the 2nd columns second, ....etc

The result should look like this:

```
array([[ 0,  9, 18,  3, 12, 21,  6, 15, 24],
       [ 1, 10, 19,  4, 13, 22,  7, 16, 25],
       [ 2, 11, 20,  5, 14, 23,  8, 17, 26]])
```

PS. also any reading material on the subject would be great!

Comment: Your question may get voted as too broad or opinion based.  But, I often find myself doing exactly what you described, playing around in ipython before coding it up.  At least know you're not alone in that strategy.

Comment: You, me and many others I suppose. I understand the risk of down voting, though I think that it can be a good discussion with the potential of being a good starting point for solving these problems, based on the many ndarray related questions I see coming by on SO

Answer (score 4):

I regularly play about with shapes in `ipython`.  However, to make things clearer, I start with array with distinct dimensions.

```
arr = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
```

That way, it's easier to identify how the axes get shifted, for example:

```
In [25]: arr.shape
Out[25]: (3, 4, 5)

In [26]: arr.T.shape
Out[26]: (5, 4, 3)

In [31]: arr.T.reshape(5,-1)
Out[31]: 
array([[ 0, 20, 40,  5, 25, 45, 10, 30, 50, 15, 35, 55],
       [ 1, 21, 41,  6, 26, 46, 11, 31, 51, 16, 36, 56],
       [ 2, 22, 42,  7, 27, 47, 12, 32, 52, 17, 37, 57],
       [ 3, 23, 43,  8, 28, 48, 13, 33, 53, 18, 38, 58],
       [ 4, 24, 44,  9, 29, 49, 14, 34, 54, 19, 39, 59]])
```

where as a different transpose (that does not switch the order of 3,4)

```
In [38]: np.transpose(arr,[2,0,1]).shape
Out[38]: (5, 3, 4)

In [39]: np.transpose(arr,[2,0,1]).reshape(5,-1)
Out[39]: 
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55],
       [ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56],
       [ 2,  7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57],
       [ 3,  8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53, 58],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59]])
```

I also like to use 'oddly' shaped arrays like this when developing functions.  That way, if I do mess up some transpose or broadcasting, dimensions errors will jump out at me.  Experience tells me that once I get the dimensions right, the values will also be correct.  Or at least the class of errors that affect values is quite different from those that affect dimensions.

I also liberally sprinkle development code with `print arr.shape` like statements, or even `assert x.shape==y.shape` assertions.

It also helps to label dimensions:

```
M, N, L = 3, 4, 5
np.empty((M,N,L))
```

or like in `einsum`

```
np.einsum('ijk,kj->i', A, B) # if A is (M,N,L), B must be (L,N)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903842/901925 is an example of trying to understand and explain `rollaxis`.

Another strategy is to look at the Python code of `numpy` functions.  Often they accept `axis` arguments.  It's instructive to see how they use those.  Sometimes that particular `axis` is rotated to the front, or to the end.  Sometimes a nd array is reshaped into a 2d array, collapsing all axes except one down to one.  Other achieve generality by constructing and manipulating an indexing tuple.  More advanced functions play with the strides as well as the shape.

Whether a dimension should be first or last is usally an optimization issue - and may involve tradeoffs between ease of use (broadcasting, indexing) and speed.  Just keep in mind that for "C" order, the last dimension forms contiguous blocks.