# Evaluate a RegularGridInterpolator on an another regular grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

I'm having trouble understanding how to shape data to evaluate an interpolated view of an nD-array, using [scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html)

Considering `A` a `(n1,n2,n3)`-shaped numpy array, indexed along the following coordinates :

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 5) # n1 = 5
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10) # n2 = 10
z = np.linspace(0, 500, 1000) # n3 = 1000
```

For this example, you can generate `A = ex_array` with this bit of code from the documentation :

```
def f(x,y,z):
    return 2 * x**3 + 3 * y**2 - z

ex_array = f(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True))
```

Let's imagine I want to interpolate the entire array along each axis.
This is done with :

```
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

interpolated = RegularGridInterpolator((x,y,z), ex_array)
```

Now, the part where my brain starts to hurt hard :
In order to evaluate this interpolator object at any given coordinates, you have to `__call__` it on said point like so :

```
evaluated_pts = interpolated((0,1,0)) # evaluate at (x,y,z) = (5,0.5,300)
print(evaluated_pts)
```

In order to evaluate it on several points, you can iterate like this :

```
pts = ((5,0.5,_z) for _z in np.linspace(100,200,50))
evaluated_pts = interpolated(pts)
```

Now, what if I want to use the same logic as above, and evaluate on an entire new grid, such as :

```
new_x = np.linspace(2, 3, 128)
new_y = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, 100)
new_z = np.linspace(350, 400, 256)
```

As you can see now, it's not as straightforward as `interpolated(new_x, new_y, new_z)`, and I tried to use np.meshgrid but could not figure it out.

Ideally, I'd want to output a new `(128, 100, 256)` array in this example.

Comment: I have the same question. As I see it, `scipy.griddata` is useful to map *unstructured* data, i.e. a cloud of points to another cloud of points.  `RGD` can map *structured* to *unstructured*.  **HOWEVER** there isn't any method to map from *structured* to *structured*.  The best you can do is pass a cloud of points into RGD, which seems very  inefficient to me.  But maybe it's no big deal :)

Answer (score 4):

`RegularGridInterpolator` input values are located on a grid. The grid points are defined using a tuple of "ticks" along each axis, for instance ((x0, x1, ..., xn), (y0, y1, ..., xm), (z0, z1, ..., zk) ) in 3D. The values are given as an nd-array of shape (n, m, k) in this case.

To evaluate the interpolated function, the assumption that the points are on a grid is no more required. Then, the asked points are defined as a list of points (actually an array of coordinates): ((x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), ... (xP, yP, zP)) i.e. a nd-array of shape (Number of points, Number of dimension).

To evaluate the interpolation on a new grid, it must be constructed using `meshgrid`.

`reshape` and `transpose` are used to transform arrays from one shape to another (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513432/how-to-determine-a-numpy-array-reshape-strategy)).

For example:

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [3, 4]
z = [5, 6, 7, 8]

xyz_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')

xyz_list = np.reshape(xyz_grid, (3, -1), order='C').T

xyz_list
```

̀`xyz_list` could be used to call the interpolation function and it looks like that:

```
array([[0, 3, 5],
       [0, 3, 6],
       [0, 3, 7],
       [0, 3, 8],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [0, 4, 6],
       [0, 4, 7],
       [0, 4, 8],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 6],
       [1, 3, 7],
       [1, 3, 8],
       [1, 4, 5],
       [1, 4, 6],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [1, 4, 8],
       [2, 3, 5],
       [2, 3, 6],
       [2, 3, 7],
       [2, 3, 8],
       [2, 4, 5],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 7],
       [2, 4, 8]])
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I ended up implementing a solution which is similar to yours in its logic but not in implementation. I'm going to post it later here as own-answer. I'll accept yours if you match it to my example data and finally output the required array ? Thank you